# Establish a link between two lists in linq to entities where clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm pretty new to `Linq` and `EF` and I'm stuck regarding how I could just link two lists in Linq to Entities.

I'm using Database First and I have two tables :

`Person`, with columns `Id`
and
`Ability`, with columns `Id`, `PersonId` and `Value`

Thus, `Person` class has a `ICollection<Ability>`, called `AllAbilities`.

In the ViewModel of some View, I get back a list of int, representing textboxes values entered by the user for `Ability.Value`, called `AbilitiesInput`.
My need is simple, in the Controller I have to call a query which would do the following:

```
GetAll(person =>
    for(i = 0; i < AbilitiesCount; i++) { person.AllAbilities[i] > AbilitiesInput[i] }
)
```

Where `GetAll` method looks like that in my generic repo :

```
public virtual async Task<List<TEntity>> GetAll(
        Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> wherePredicate = null
{ ... }
```

To resume, I just need a boolean which could check if every `AllAbilities[i]` is upper to `AbilitiesInput[i]`, but nothing I tried has worked.
I tried to change `AbilitiesInput` to `List<KeyValuePair>` or `List<Tuple>` but got an error saying that `No mapping exists`, tried to use a `Select` to create a new object, also tried to use `IndexOf` or `FindIndex` to get index without foreach...

If anyone could explain me how I can achieve this simple thing I would be so, so glad.
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What property of the `Ability` entity does `AbilitiesInput` represent - `Value`?

Comment: Not clear though what are you searching for. Return persons with (1) **all** abilities bigger than **all** ability input or (2) **any** ability bigger than **any** ability input or (3) compare by index? Note that for (3), person.Abilities does not have a defined order.

Comment: AbilityInput represents textboxes where the user enters the min value for the current ability value. Thus I would need a boolean checking if every AllAbilities[i] > AbilityInput[i]. For example if AllAbilities[0] <= AbilityInput[0] and AllAbilities[1] > AbilityInput[1] I want to return false. But if AllAbilities[i] > AbilityInput[i] for each value of i, I would like to return true.

Comment: So it's (3). I think that "simple thing" cannot be represented with EF compatible expression.

Comment: Really ? :( Oh, well, what could I do then ?

Comment: If a Person has a collection of Abilities, I guess they can be matched by Ability.Id?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I'm pretty new to `Linq` and `EF`

You are out of luck, because "this simple thing" is relatively easy in LINQ to Objects, but quite hard (almost impossible) in LINQ to Entities.

In order to somehow solve it, you need to build manually LINQ to Entities compatible `Expression`.

First, you'll need some helpers for building expression predicates. [PredicateBuilder](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) is a popular choice, but it does not produce EF compatible expressions and requires `LinqKit` and `AsExpandable` inside the repository. So I use the below helpers which are similar, but produce final compatible expressions:

```
public static class PredicateUtils
{
    sealed class Predicate<T>
    {
        public static readonly Expression<Func<T, bool>> True = item => true;
        public static readonly Expression<Func<T, bool>> False = item => false;
    }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Null<T>() { return null; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return Predicate<T>.True; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return Predicate<T>.False; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
    {
        if (Equals(left, right)) return left;
        if (left == null || Equals(left, True<T>())) return right;
        if (right == null || Equals(right, True<T>())) return left;
        if (Equals(left, False<T>()) || Equals(right, False<T>())) return False<T>();
        var body = Expression.AndAlso(left.Body, right.Body.Replace(right.Parameters[0], left.Parameters[0]));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, left.Parameters);
    }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
    {
        if (Equals(left, right)) return left;
        if (left == null || Equals(left, False<T>())) return right;
        if (right == null || Equals(right, False<T>())) return left;
        if (Equals(left, True<T>()) || Equals(right, True<T>())) return True<T>();
        var body = Expression.OrElse(left.Body, right.Body.Replace(right.Parameters[0], left.Parameters[0]));
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(body, left.Parameters);
    }

    static Expression Replace(this Expression expression, Expression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ExpressionReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ExpressionReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public Expression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.Visit(node);
        }
    }
}
```

Second, define a helper method in your controller for a single criteria like this

```
static Expression<Func<Person, bool>> AbilityFilter(int index, int value)
{
    return p => p.AllAbilities.OrderBy(a => a.Id).Skip(index).Take(1).Any(a => a.Value > value);
}
```

Finally, build the filter and pass it to `GetAll` method:

```
var filter = PredicateUtils.Null<Person>();
for (int i = 0; i < AbilitiesInput.Count; i++)
    filter = filter.And(AbilityFilter(i, AbilitiesInput[i]));
GetAll(filter);
```

The techniques used are definitely not for a novice, but I see no simple way to solve that particular problem.

Comment: I always use [this predicate builder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) exactly for the reasons you mention wrt Linqkit.

Comment: So many thanks Ivan, it works perfectly fine and honestly, you made my day ! So nice of you to help like that ;)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I got it right, but the code below may help get correct solution.  Using (x,i) will enumerate through the collection and get an index so you can compare the two collections.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List<TextBox> AbilitiesInput = null;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AbilitiesInput = new List<TextBox>() { textBox1, textBox2, textBox3, textBox4 };

            Person person = new Person();
            List<Ability> results = person.AllAbilities.Where((x, i) => x.Value > int.Parse(AbilitiesInput[i].Text)).ToList();
        }
    }
    public class Person
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<Ability> AllAbilities { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            AllAbilities = new List<Ability>();
        }

    }
    public class Ability
    {
        public int Id { get; set;}
        public int PersonId { get; set; }
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply, however in order to use it in the where clause of my query I would need a boolean instead of the `List<Ability> results`. How could I change it into boolean ? I tried to replace `Where` with `All` but `All` does not seem to handle `(x, i)`. Should I use `Count` on the results list ?

Comment: Did you try 'ANY' which returns a boolean?