# Creating dynamic queries using ParameterExpression in Odata Client

Tags: c#, linq, odata, iqueryable, odata-v4

I'm consuming an Odata v4 service using Odata Client Code generator proxy class.

```
MetroContext = new MetroContainer(new Uri(@"http://localhost:56222/service"));
IQueryable<Patient> query = MetroContext.Patients;
query = query.Where(x => x.FirstName == "john");
```

Above code is working fine. But I need to build queries dynamically. So I have tried following:

```
MetroContext = new MetroContainer(new Uri(@"http://localhost:56222/service"));
IQueryable<Patient> query = MetroContext.Patients;

ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(typeof(Patient), "patient");
Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, "FirstName");
Expression right = Expression.Constant("john");
Expression predicateBody = Expression.Equal(left, right);

query = query.Provider.CreateQuery<Patient>(predicateBody);
```

When I run the program I'm getting an error message:

> Error translating Linq expression to URI: The binary operator 'Equal'
>   is not supported.

- Why I'm getting this error and how can I solve this?
- How can I create dynamic queries by combining methods such as `Contains()` , `StartsWith()` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test that specific query provider, but at the first place `predicateBody` is not a valid expression for any provider.

Instead, you need to build `Expression<Func<Patient, bool>>` expression and pass it to the `Where` method like this:

```
// ...
var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<Patient, bool>>(predicateBody, pe);
query = query.Where(predicate);
```

What about your second question, you need to use some of the [Expression.Call](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.expression.call(v=vs.110).aspx) overloads. For instance:

```
Expression predicateBody = Expression.Call(left, "Contains", null, right);
```

Similar for "StartsWith" and "EndWith" etc.

Comment: thanks, it's working perfectly. One more question, Can I use `Equal`, `GreaterThan` comparison in `Expression.Call()` method?

Comment: No. `Call` is for methods. But of course you can use `Equal`, `GreaterThan` etc. in method arguments (for conditions). Do you have a specific example?

Comment: Can I replace the code `Expression.NotEqual(left, right)` with something like `Expression.Call(left, "NotEqual", null, right)` ?

Comment: No. These are operators, not methods.

Comment: Ok, now I understand. Thanks.

Comment: Does this work with dynamically generating "OR" expressions?  Trying to loop through some collection objects to generate OR's and having problems with a normal predicatebuilder.

Comment: @Matt Not sure exactly about the question. If you have problems with the "normal" PredicateBuilder, you might check my answer to [Establish a link between two lists in linq to entities where clause](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246162/establish-a-link-between-two-lists-in-linq-to-entities-where-clause/36247259#36247259) or the [Universal PredicateBuilder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/)

Comment: Shucking perfect. Thanks!