# Filtering search results on column on a different table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am a novice at c# and MVC. I have seen a few similar questions to my problem, but nothing that has helped me address this problem yet. I'm looking for some more specific guidance.

I am trying to filter search results using a specific column in a related table. I am displaying a list of `Shifts`. Each shift has `StoreNum` as a foreign key. `StoreNum` is the primary key for the `Stores` table. The `Stores` table contains, among other things, a column called `Area`. I want the user to be able to click a checkbox and have the results filter on `Area`.

Here is my method in my controller (I have omitted some code that currently works and seems unrelated):

```
        [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult OpenShiftList(DateTime? searchStartDate = null, DateTime? searchEndDate = null, DateTime? searchStartTime = null, DateTime? searchEndTime = null, Boolean? searchStore = null, Boolean? searchArea = false, Boolean? searchDistrict = false)
    {
        var thisStore = User.StoreNum();
        var data =
                    from s in db.Shifts
                   select s;
            if (searchDistrict == true)
        {
            data = data.Where(s => db.Stores.Select(x => x.District.Where(x.StoreNum == thisStore)));
        }

        data = data.Where(s => s.IsCovered.Equals(false));
         return View(data.ToList());
    }
```

I am being given the error `"Argument 2: cannot convert 'bool' to 'System.Func<char, bool>'`

For reference, here is the HTML in my view that relates to this:

```
        <div class="col-md-2 well">
        <div class="form-group">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("OpenShiftList", "Shifts", FormMethod.Get))
            {
                <p>
                    Date @Html.TextBox("searchStartDate", "", new { @class = "date-picker" }) to @Html.TextBox("searchEndDate", "", new { @class = "date-picker" })
                </p><p>
                Start Time @Html.TextBox("searchStartTime", "", new { @class = "timepicker" })
                </p><p>
                    End Time @Html.TextBox("searchEndTime", "", new { @class = "timepicker" })
                </p><p>
                    My Store @Html.CheckBox("searchStore")
                </p><p>
                    My District @Html.CheckBox("searchDistrict")
            </p><p>
                    My Area     @Html.CheckBox("searchArea")
            </p><p>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary btn-md" />
                </p>
                }
    </div>
</div>
    </div>
```

Is there a way to achieve this filtering goal with the way I currently have things set up? Do I need to use a viewmodel instead?

**EDIT**
Here is the class for `Shift`

```
public int ShiftID { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode =true)]
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name="Start Time")]
    public System.DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name ="End Time")]
    public System.DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Store Number")]
    public string StoreNum { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Covered")]
    public bool IsCovered { get; set; }
```

And here is the class for `Store`:

```
    [Display(Name="Store Number")]
    public string StoreNum { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Store Name")]
    public string StoreName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Store Address")]
    public string StreetAddr { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string District { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
```

Thanks for any guidance and feedback on this and any other part of my code... it helps me learn!

Comment: What does `Shifts` and `Stores` and any relevant relations look like?

Comment: You're trying to get _all the shifts for a given StoreNum_? _Then filtered by Area and/or District_? If you get a store by StoreNum wouldn't that only return one item? If so, then an additional filter on Area and District would still return that one item making the filter redundant? Is the StoreNum a duplicate value? I'm missing something here.

Comment: Each StoreNum is unique, but each District and Area has multiple stores. I want to retrieve a list of all shifts for all stores in a given district or area. Sorry for my lack of clarity!

Comment: Some additional clarity... what I am basically trying to do is retrieve all shifts that are in the same area as the user. My thought process was that I could just retrieve all shifts whose associated Store object had the same Area as the user's Store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue using Jasen's idea of performing a join.

```
            var GetArea = from shift in db.Shifts
                       join store in db.Stores on shift.StoreNum equals store.StoreNum
                       where store.StoreNum == thisStore
                       select store.Area;
            var thisArea = GetArea.First();
```

This allowed me to store the `Area` for the user's `Store`. Then...

```
            if (searchArea == true)
        {
            data = from shift in db.Shifts
                               join store in db.Stores on shift.StoreNum equals store.StoreNum
                               where store.Area.Contains(thisArea)
                               select shift;
        }
```

This allowed me to filter for `Area`. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution than mine, but this works.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to join `Shift` and `Store` first on `StoreNum` to get each store's shifts. You can build your where clause before the join.

Because you're querying against a database we'll need to build Expressions.

```
Expression<Func<StoreShift, bool>> hasStoreNum = (s) => s.Shift.StoreNum == storeNum;
Expression<Func<StoreShift, bool>> hasArea = (s) => s.Shift.Area == s.Store.Area;
Expression<Func<StoreShift, bool>> hasDistrict = (s) => s.Shift.District == s.Store.District;

var predicates = new List<Expression<Func<StoreShift, bool>>>();
predicates.Add(hasStoreNum);

if (searchArea)
{
    predicates.Add(hasArea);
}
if (searchDistrict)
{
    predicates.Add(hasDistrict);
}

var query = from shift in db.Shifts
            join store in db.Stores on shift.StoreNum equals store.StoreNum
            select new StoreShift { Store = store, Shift = shift };

var result = query.WhereAny(predicates).Select(s => s.Shift);
```

You'll need some helper classes

```
public class StoreShift
{
    public Store Store { get; set; }
    public Shift Shift { get; set; }
}
```

I got the implementation for the classes below [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38095481/2030565)

```
public static class QueryableExtensions
{
    public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T>(this IQueryable<T> source, IEnumerable<Expression<Func<T, bool>>> predicates)
    {
        if (predicates == null || !predicates.Any()) return source;

        var predicate = predicates.Aggregate((a, b) => Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
            Expression.Or(a.Body, b.Body.ReplaceParameter(b.Parameters[0], a.Parameters[0])),
            a.Parameters[0]));
        return source.Where(predicate);
    }
}
public static class ExpressionUtils
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression expression, ParameterExpression source, Expression target)
    {
        return new ParameterReplacer { Source = source, Target = target }.Visit(expression);
    }

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Source;
        public Expression Target;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
        {
            return node == Source ? Target : base.VisitParameter(node);
        }
    }
}
```

This was the simplest Expression builder implementation I could find. There are also NuGet libraries that help you build Expressions dynamically.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. When I run this bit of code, I get the error `System.NotSupportedException: The LINQ expression node type Invoke is not supported in LINQ to Entitites.` Any thoughts?