# LINQ expressions predicate add where clause

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, expression

I want to add extra "where" clause into the following expression.

```
public Task<IEnumerable<MyClass>> Find(Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>> predicate)
 {
   return _documentDbProvider.Find(predicate);
 }
```

such as `.where(t=>t.tenantId == tenant.id)`

so my db provider gets two "where" clauses, thanks

Comment: You can compose new expression using and operator or extend yours _documentDbProvider.Find method to accept: params Expression<Func<MyClass, bool>>[] predicates. Second approach seems to be much easier, which one do you prefer?

Comment: You want to use `Find()` and select all IEnumerable  using where clause?

Comment: I would prefer 1st approach, and after googling I seem to not find any examples.

Comment: @mww yes, find uses predicate in db provider and adds where clause. `            return _client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(collection.DocumentsLink)
                .Where(predicate)
                .AsEnumerable();` 
so I want to be tenant aware. that only can be selected for this tenant.

Comment: Can show how You call now your `Find()` method. How look now your predicate?

Comment: There are a lot of them actually, but this decision will definitely made yours code less readable and less maintainable. Here is a link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/457316/combining-two-expressions-expressionfunct-bool.

Comment: that is in service `        public Task<IEnumerable<Depot>> GetDepotsAsync()
        {
            return _repository.Find(x=>x.DepotName == depotName);
        }`

Comment: What about `_repository.Find(x=>x.DepotName == depotName && x.tenantId == tenant.id );` ?

Comment: so in nutshell, in services I populate depot class properties, in repository I populate base class properties for the depot. also repo can get / find only depots that belongs to that tenant. I dont want to manipulate low level tenant interactions in services.

Comment: I want to move tenant info one level down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are seeking for a way to combine an existing predicate with another one using `And`. You can use some expression predicate builder helper class - like [Universal Predicate Builder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) or my own `PredicateUtils` from  [Establish a link between two lists in linq to entities where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246162/establish-a-link-between-two-lists-in-linq-to-entities-where-clause/36247259#36247259) post and similar. It allows you to use something like this:

```
return _documentDbProvider.Find(predicate.And(t => t.tenantId == tenant.id));
```