# Call Expression within a LINQ to Entities with LINQkit

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I am testing the predicateBuilder and I am getting this error

**The LINQ expression node type 'Invoke' is not supported in LINQ to Entities.**
here is my code

```
 public partial class Product
{
    public static Expression<Func<UserAddress, bool>> IsSelling()
    {
        return p => p.ispeacc == true;
    }
}
public partial class Product
{
    public static Expression<Func<UserAddress, bool>> ContainsInDescription()
    {
        var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<UserAddress>();

        predicate = predicate.Or(p => p.accNumber == "i****");

        return predicate;
    }
}
public class Accounts
{
    public UserAddress GetAccount()
    {
        var repositoryUAdd = new Repository<UserAddress>();
        var ispor = Product.IsSelling();
        var acc = Product.ContainsInDescription();
        UserAddress accInforesult = repositoryUAdd.GetEntitybybool(ispor.And(acc));

        return accInforesult;

    }
}

public T GetEntitybybool(
      Expression<Func<T, bool>> filter)
    {

        return DbSet.Where(filter).DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault();

    }
```

Any idea what I am doing wrong

Comment: Does the error occurs right after this line  :`return DbSet.Where(filter).DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault(); ?`

Answer (score 0):

The `PredicateBuilder` class from LinqKit is not directly compatible with EF. So you either switch to another predicate builder library that has no such issues (like [Universal PredicateBuilder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) or my own `PredicateUtils` class from my answer to [Establish a link between two lists in linq to entities where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246162/establish-a-link-between-two-lists-in-linq-to-entities-where-clause/36247259#36247259)), or if you want to stay with LinqKit, then either use `Expand` custom method on the resulting predicate:

```
    UserAddress accInforesult = repositoryUAdd.GetEntitybybool(ispor.And(acc).Expand());
```

or `AsExpandable` on the query source:

```
return DbSet.AsExpandable().Where(filter).DefaultIfEmpty(null).FirstOrDefault();
```