# How can I convert IQueryable expression object into LINQ expression?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, linq, expression

I need to be able to create LINQ's `Where` conditions/filters dynamically from a controller. Then, I want to pass these filters to a repository's method that will query the database after applying the dynamic filters using LINQ's `Where` extension.

Here is the code that I execute in my controller which dynamically creates filters using the `IQueryable` object

```
IQueryable<StageModel> stage = null;

if(model.ClientId != null)
{
    stage = stage.Where(s => s.ClientId == model.ClientId);
}

if (model.CategoryIds != null && model.CategoryIds.Any())
{
    var stageIds = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 }; // this will be dynamically generated

    stage = stage.Where(s => stageIds.Contains(s.Id));
}

Stages = unitOfWork.Stages.GetStagesPagedList(1, PerPage, stage.Expression as MethodCallExpression);

... 
...
```

Finally, in my repository I have this method that takes `Expression<Func<StageModel, bool>>` expression in the third argument and passes it to the `Where` extension if it isn't null.

```
public IPagedList<StageModel> GetStagesPagedList(int pageNumber, int pageSize, Expression<Func<StageModel, bool>> predicate = null)
{
    IQueryable<StageModel> stages = CastedContext.Stages;

    if (predicate != null)
     {
         stages = stages.Where(predicate);
     }

     return stages.OrderBy(stage => stage.Name)
                  .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

}
```

But I am getting an error on the following line

```
unitOfWork.Stages.GetStagesPagedList(1, PerPage, stage.Expression as MethodCallExpression)
```

This is what the error shows

> Error 3   Argument 3: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'

I also tried not casing the expression like so 
unitOfWork.Stages.GetStagesPagedList(1, PerPage, stage.Expression)

> Error 3   Argument 3: cannot convert from
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression' to
>   'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression>'

How can I correctly do the conversion? Is this isn't possible, how can I dynamically create filters and pass them to my repository?

Comment: How do you construct your stage.Expression? It shouldn't be MethodCallExpression, it should be LambdaExpression i guess

Comment: Why don't you add expressions to `unitOfWork.Stages` instead of `stage`?

Comment: @MaksimSimkin I construct my method as you see in my code. I construct it in the controller and then I pass it to the `GetStagesPagedList` method

Answer (score 2):

Simply have `GetStagesPagedList` accept the `IQueryable` that you have, rather than an `Expression`.

```
public IPagedList<StageModel> GetStagesPagedList(IQueryable<StageModel> stages, 
    int pageNumber, int pageSize)
{
     return stages.OrderBy(stage => stage.Name)
         .ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);
}
```

I don't know that that's doing enough to really warrant another method, but you're free to use it if you want.

Also your caller has a major bug in that you initialize the `IQueryable` to `null`, when you need to initialize it to the data context's table:

```
IQueryable<StageModel> stages = CastedContext.Stages;

//...

Stages = unitOfWork.Stages.GetStagesPagedList(stages, 1, PerPage);
```

Comment: The caller does not have access to `CastedContext.Stages` which is why I am not initializing it with `CastedContext.Stages` However, in the `GetStagesPagedList` method, I check if the argument is null or not. I am not sure if I am missing something else

Comment: @MikeA Your code is going to throw a null argument exception any time you call `Where` because you're calling `Where` on a `null` queryable.  That will just break.  You need to actually have the base queryable from the data source in order to construct a query.  I'd *strongly* consider re-designing your solution such that you simply have access to it `(or an `IQueryable` provided through some layers of indirection) when constructing your query.

Comment: Are you saying I should have a getter method that returns the `CastedContext.Stages` then use that method to build `IQuerable` object and then pass it as an argument?

Comment: @MikeA It's hard to say without knowing more about the design of your application.  All I can say is that you should have an `iQueryable` in whatever location is responsible for constructing the query.  How you can best provide it to that location is beyond what I have enough information to comment on.

Answer (score 1):

Using fake `IQueryable` to build predicate is not a good idea. The chained `Where` technique is applicable when you have the actual `IQueryable`. In order to build predicate expression, all you need is some predicate builder helper utility.

For instance, you can take my own `PredicateUtils` class from [Establish a link between two lists in linq to entities where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246162/establish-a-link-between-two-lists-in-linq-to-entities-where-clause/36247259#36247259). It perfectly fits because handles `null` predicates.

Copy/paste the class to your project, then use something like this (basically replace `stage = stage.Where` with `predicate = predicate.And`):

```
var predicate = PredicateUtils.Null<StageModel>();

if(model.ClientId != null)
{
    predicate = predicate.And(s => s.ClientId == model.ClientId);
}

if (model.CategoryIds != null && model.CategoryIds.Any())
{
    var stageIds = new List<int>{ 1, 2, 3 }; // this will be dynamically generated

    predicate = predicate.And(s => stageIds.Contains(s.Id));
}

Stages = unitOfWork.Stages.GetStagesPagedList(1, PerPage, predicate);

... 
...
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually create an `Expression` like this:

```
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof(StagedModel), "s");
Expression stage = null;
if (model.ClientId != null)
{
    stage = Expression.Equal(Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "ClientId"), Expression.Constant(model.ClientId));
}
if (model.CategoryIds != null && model.CategoryIds.Any())
{
    var stageIds = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };    
    Expression contains = null;
    foreach (var id in stageIds)
    {
        var equals = Expression.Equal(Expression.Constant(id), Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, "Id"));
        contains = contains == null ? equals : Expression.OrElse(contains, equals);
    }

    stage = stage == null ? stage : Expression.AndAlso(stage, contains);
}    
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<StagedModel, bool>>(stage, parameter);
Stages = unitOfWork.Stages.GetStagesPagedList(1, PerPage, stage);
```