# Add dynamically predicate to expression without PredicateBuilder

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6, linq-to-entities

I use `linqToEntities` and would like to add `OR` condition dynamically.

I know that [there is a great library `PredicateBuilder` by brother Albahari](http://www.albahari.com/nutshell/predicatebuilder.aspx) and it can solve my task, but I cannot use it.

My conditions looks like this:

```
IEnumerable<Condition> conditions = new List<Condition>()
{
    new Condition(){IdReference = 1, TableName = "Table1" },
    new Condition(){IdReference = 2, TableName = "Table2" },
    new Condition(){IdReference = 3, TableName = "Table3" }, 
    // and so on
};
```

What I have is:

```
var histories = db.History as IQueryable<History>;
foreach (var cond in conditions)
{
     //What code should be here to be translated into:
     /*
     histories = histories
        .Where(h => h.IdReference == 1 && h.TableName =="Table1" 
            || h.IdReference == 2 && h.TableName == "Table2"
            || h.IdReference == 3 && h.TableName == "Table3");
            // and so on
     */
}
```

However, I do not know in advance how many `conditions` would be. 
How is it possible to add `OR` conditions dynamically from `IEnumerable<Condition>`?

Comment: If you don't have too many combinations, just use some conditions: `if(thisIsTheCase){ histories = histories.Where(// put your conditions} else if(another Case){ histories = histories.Where(// put your conditions}` add more if else until you have covered all cases. You can also do it by creating dynamic expressions but it will not be easy because you will need to combine the expressions.

Comment: Why can you not use `PredicateBuilder`?

Comment: @CodingYoshi as my code will not be passed a code review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what's the problem with using predicate builder - it doesn't have to be LINQ Kit package, the so called predicate builder is usually a single static class with 2 extension methods - like [Universal Predicate Builder](https://petemontgomery.wordpress.com/2011/02/10/a-universal-predicatebuilder/) or my own `PredicateUtils` from [Establish a link between two lists in linq to entities where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246162/establish-a-link-between-two-lists-in-linq-to-entities-where-clause/36247259#36247259) and similar.

Anyway, once you want it, of course it could be built using just plain [Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) class static methods.

Add the following in order to eliminate the need of writing `Expression.` before each call:

```
using static System.Linq.Expressions.Expression;
```

and then use something like this:

```
if (conditions.Any())
{
    var parameter = Parameter(typeof(History));
    var body = conditions
        .Select(condition => Expression.Constant(condition))
        .Select(condition => Expression.AndAlso(
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, nameof(History.IdReference)),
            Expression.Convert(
                  Expression.PropertyOrField(condition, nameof(Condition.IdReference))
                , Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, nameof(History.IdReference)).Type)
        ),
        Expression.Equal(
            Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, nameof(History.TableName)),
            Expression.Convert(
                  Expression.PropertyOrField(condition, nameof(Condition.TableName))
                , Expression.PropertyOrField(parameter, nameof(History.TableName)).Type)
         )
        ))
        .Aggregate(Expression.OrElse);                      
    var predicate = Lambda<Func<History, bool>>(body, parameter);
    histories = histories.Where(predicate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you mean

```
var histories = db.History as IQueryable<History>;
foreach (var cond in conditions)
{
     //What code should be here to be translated into:

     histories = histories
        .Where(h => h.IdReference == cond.IdReference && 
      h.TableName ==cond.TableName );

}
```

Comment: He does not know the conditions until runtime. This will work if they were known.

Comment: As I understood he dose not know how many conditions in History list but he have fixed conditions in conditionList so looping in conditionList and comparing !! As I thought :)

Comment: Chaining `Where`s is the equivilent of `and` not `or`.