# Why runtime Expressions cause collisions on the Cache of Entity Framework Core 5?

Tags: c#, mysql, .net-core, reflection, entity-framework-core

Before I forget it, my execution context, I'm using .Net 5 with the packages:

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design 5.0.6
- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational 5.0.6
- MySql.EntityFrameworkCore 5.0.3.1

My main goal was to remove the repetitive task of doing expressions when I need to retrieve entities, something like:

```
public class GetListEntity
{
   property int QueryProperty { get; set }
}

public class Entity
{
   property int Property { get; set }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> List(GetListEntity getListEntity)
{
   var restrictions = new List<Expression<Func<Entity>
   if (model.QueryProperty != null)
   { 
      restrictions.Add(e => e.Property == model.QueryProperty);
   }
   nonTrackedQueryableEntities = this.dbContext.Set<Entity>()
                                               .AsNoTracking();

   var expectedEntity = restrictions.Aggregate((sr, nr) => sr.And(nr)); //The And method is below as an extension
   var expectedNonTrackedQueryableEntities = nonTrackedQueryableEntities.Where(expectedEntity);

   // I will get the total first because the API was meant to paginate the responses.
   var total = await expectedNonTrackedQueryableEntities.CountAsync();
}


public static class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> selfExpression, Expression<Func<T, bool>> otherExpression)
    {
        return selfExpression.Compose(otherExpression, Expression.OrElse);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> selfExpression, Expression<Func<T, bool>> otherExpression)
    {
        return selfExpression.Compose(otherExpression, Expression.AndAlso);
    }

    private static InvocationExpression Casting<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> selfExpression, Expression<Func<T, bool>> otherExpression)
    {
        return Expression.Invoke(otherExpression, selfExpression.Parameters.Cast<Expression>());
    }

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Compose<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> selfExpression, Expression<Func<T, bool>> otherExpression, Func<Expression, Expression, Expression> merge)
    {
        var invocationExpression = selfExpression.Casting(otherExpression);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(merge(selfExpression.Body, invocationExpression), selfExpression.Parameters);
    }
}
```

I've managed to achieve what I wanted but let's say... partially, because if I try to Query the Database at least two times in a row I get this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: An item with the same key has already been added. Key: e
   at System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.TryInsert(TKey key, TValue value, InsertionBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareLambda(LambdaExpression a, LambdaExpression b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareBinary(BinaryExpression a, BinaryExpression b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareLambda(LambdaExpression a, LambdaExpression b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareUnary(UnaryExpression a, UnaryExpression b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareExpressionList(IReadOnlyList`1 a, IReadOnlyList`1 b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareMethodCall(MethodCallExpression a, MethodCallExpression b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareExpressionList(IReadOnlyList`1 a, IReadOnlyList`1 b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareMethodCall(MethodCallExpression a, MethodCallExpression b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareExpressionList(IReadOnlyList`1 a, IReadOnlyList`1 b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.CompareMethodCall(MethodCallExpression a, MethodCallExpression b)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.ExpressionComparer.Compare(Expression left, Expression right)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionEqualityComparer.Equals(Expression x, Expression y)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.CompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.CompiledQueryCacheKey.Equals(CompiledQueryCacheKey other)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.RelationalCompiledQueryCacheKey.Equals(RelationalCompiledQueryCacheKey other)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.MySQLCompiledQueryCacheKey.Equals(MySQLCompiledQueryCacheKey other)
   at MySql.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.MySQLCompiledQueryCacheKeyGenerator.MySQLCompiledQueryCacheKey.Equals(Object obj)
   at System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary`2.TryGetValue(TKey key, TValue& value)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.MemoryCache.TryGetValue(Object key, Object& result)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.CacheExtensions.TryGetValue[TItem](IMemoryCache cache, Object key, TItem& value)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression query, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.ExecuteAsync[TResult](Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.ExecuteAsync[TSource,TResult](MethodInfo operatorMethodInfo, IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.EntityFrameworkQueryableExtensions.CountAsync[TSource](IQueryable`1 source, CancellationToken cancellationToken)'
```

Following the trace I managed to discover that the ORM is caching for some reason my expressions (and putting the parameter name, in this case 'e') and failing to detect a key collision the second time it has a similar expression to query the database. I said for some reason because, it's not the main deal but at least is odd that cache is involved in a non tracked query, maybe I'm missing something in the middle.

To undenrstand how i got here i will put the code below.

First an interface to implement in every model related with querying a list of entities and expose the extension method ListRestrictions (almost at the bottom).

```
public interface IEntityFilter<TEntity>
{ 
}
```

The next step was to define Attributes to summarize the action to do with the property and generate a partial expression to use in the extension method:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public abstract class FilterByPropertyAttribute : Attribute
    {
        protected string FirstPropertyPath { get; }

        protected IEnumerable<string> NPropertyPath { get; }

        public FilterByPropertyAttribute(string firstPropertyPath, params string[] nPropertyPath)
        {
            this.FirstPropertyPath = firstPropertyPath;
            this.NPropertyPath = nPropertyPath;
        }

        protected MemberExpression GetPropertyExpression(ParameterExpression parameterExpression)
        {
            var propertyExpression = Expression.Property(parameterExpression, this.FirstPropertyPath);
            foreach (var propertyPath in this.NPropertyPath)
            {
                propertyExpression = Expression.Property(propertyExpression, propertyPath);
            }
            return propertyExpression;
        }

       public abstract Expression GetExpression(ParameterExpression parameterExpression, object propertyValue);
    }
```

And to avoid comparisons with nullable structs

```
    public abstract class NonNullableValuePropertyFilterAttribute : FilterByPropertyAttribute
    {
        public NonNullableValuePropertyFilterAttribute(string firstPropertyPath, params string[] nPropertyPath)
            : base(firstPropertyPath, nPropertyPath)
        {
        }

        public override Expression GetExpression(ParameterExpression parameterExpression, object propertyValue)
        {
            var propertyExpression = this.GetPropertyExpression(parameterExpression);
            return this.GetExpression(propertyExpression, this.GetConvertedConstantExpression(propertyExpression, Expression.Constant(propertyValue)));
        }

        protected abstract Expression GetExpression(MemberExpression memberExpression, UnaryExpression unaryExpression);

        private UnaryExpression GetConvertedConstantExpression(MemberExpression memberExpression, ConstantExpression constantExpression)
        {
            var convertedConstantExpression = Expression.Convert(constantExpression, memberExpression.Type);
            return convertedConstantExpression;
        }
    }
```

An Attribute with a defined role would be:

```
    public class EqualPropertyFilterAttribute : NonNullableValuePropertyFilterAttribute
    {

        public EqualPropertyFilterAttribute(string firstPropertyPath, params string[] nPropertyPath)
            : base(firstPropertyPath, nPropertyPath)
        {
        }

        protected override Expression GetExpression(MemberExpression memberExpression, UnaryExpression unaryExpression)
        {
            return Expression.Equal(memberExpression, unaryExpression);
        }
    }
```

And last, the extension itself:

```
    public static class EntityFilterExtensions
    {
        public static List<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>> ListRestrictions<TEntity>(this IEntityFilter<TEntity> entityFilter)
        {
            var entityFilterType = entityFilter.GetType();            
            var propertiesInfo = entityFilterType.GetProperties()
                                                 .Where(pi => pi.GetValue(entityFilter) != null 
                                                              && pi.CustomAttributes.Any(ca => ca.AttributeType
                                                                                                 .IsSubclassOf(typeof(FilterByPropertyAttribute))));

            var expressions = Enumerable.Empty<Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>>();
            if (propertiesInfo.Any())
            {
                var entityType = typeof(TEntity);
                var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "e");
                expressions =  propertiesInfo.Select(pi =>
                {
                    var filterByPropertyAttribute = Attribute.GetCustomAttribute(pi, typeof(FilterByPropertyAttribute)) as FilterByPropertyAttribute;
                    var propertyValue = pi.GetValue(entityFilter);
                    var expression = filterByPropertyAttribute.GetExpression(parameterExpression, propertyValue);
                    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TEntity, bool>>(expression, parameterExpression);
                });
            }

            return expressions.ToList();
        }
    }
```

A usage would be:

```
public class GetListEntity : IEntityFilter<Entity>
{
   [EqualPropertyFilter(nameof(Entity.Property))]
   property int QueryProperty { get; set }
}

public class Entity
{
   property int Property { get; set }
}

public async Task<ActionResult> List(GetListEntity getListEntity)
{
   var restrictions = getListEntity.ListRestrictions();
   nonTrackedQueryableEntities = this.dbContext.Set<Entity>()
                                               .AsNoTracking();

   var expectedEntity = restrictions.Aggregate((sr, nr) => sr.And(nr));
   var expectedNonTrackedQueryableEntities = nonTrackedQueryableEntities .Where(expectedEntity);

   // I will get the total first because the API was meant to paginate the responses.
   var total = await expectedNonTrackedQueryableEntities.CountAsync();
}
```

And to be discarded, if I Aggregate a non dynamic expression of a list of expressions, the ORM works fine, when I do it with the dynamic ones I get the exception at the beginning.

I found a workaround, changing in the extension method this line:

```
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(entityType, "e");
```

For this one:

```
var parameterExpression = Expression.Parameter(entityType, $"{entityType.Name}{entityFilter.GetHashCode()}");
```

I wanna know why this happens and maybe if there is another way to fix it.
I posted here before opening a thread in any Github repository because I'm still curious if is a fault of mine for missing something in the way or a bug.

Comment: Have you tried that with Pomelo provider?

Comment: First you make sure to provide repro (if you go to GitHub, they'll ask the same) because I cannot reproduce with this code. The culprit could in the code you didn't show  - the one marked with *"Add all the queryable properties and Aggregate the Expression on the variable expectedEntity"*. Second (unrelated), you'd better not bind constant expressions, but properties of the filter object, thus simulating closure and allowing EF Core to map it to a db parameter.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv yes, I tried it and got the same error, then I tried querying without this expressions and it worked like a charm again. But it will me at the start point with the vanilla code.

Comment: @IvanStoev 1) Perfect, I will upload the info removing the comment and adding the code, I didn't upload it because I felt that the explanation was too long.
2) I didn't get you there, I'm trying to make an expression like e => e.Property == 1, what is the benefit with literally make the expression like the original e => e.Property == model.QueryProperty? I'm not complaing at all but what I see is that I will need to use the model object again to retreive the properties, the intention was to avoid calling again the object when I can obtain the values at the moment I list the restrctions.

Comment: @NoName Re: (2) The benefit is that EF Core will create parameterized query, e.g. `... WHERE [table].[column] = @param`, which in general is better since db query optimizers can cache and reuse the query plans. With literal values embedded inside the SQL they have to recompile the SQL query every time

Comment: @IvanStoev, Nice, I thought that a value or property was the same to EF Core in this scenario, that the permormance would be the same, maybe is not the issue but its really good to know it.

Comment: Here `(sr, nr) => sr.And(nr)` the `And` method is from LinkKit predicate builder or something else? Is it using parameter replacement or invocation expression? Could you include it as well?

Comment: @IvanStoev No, no, it's a custom extension, I putted the method below the first appearance, in the static class ExpressionExtensions.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately it still doesn't want to reproduce on my side, thus there is nothing I can do. `Expression.Invoke` is causing issues with some EF versions, but not in this one (at least at my side). Can you reproduce it in a clean project with the only code from the question? Also, to be hundred percent sure it is not because of the usage of the `Expression.Invoke`, try replacing your `And` method with the `And` method from here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36246162/establish-a-link-between-two-lists-in-linq-to-entities-where-clause/36247259#36247259

Comment: @IvanStoev, replacing my extension with yours it worked, the exception is gone, so I what I can assume is... I was creating valid expressions for common use in memory but not very compatible with Linq to Entities, so EF Core could interpret the expression and execute it but was malformed in a way that couldn't do anything else.
Just to know, I can use the Solution of that question or do you recommend to seek any other framework or pattern for doing my expressions? As you can see I really don't have much of the knowledge for creating tree expressions by hand.

Comment: The essential is to use parameter replacer instead of `Expression.Invoke`. In other words, you simulate "calling" lambda expression by replacing parameters inside the body with the "arguments" (other expressions). Using the code from my version of predicate builder is perfectly fine. I have equivalent of `Compose` in some other posts (even though I use different names, like `Map`, `Bind`, `Apply`, even `Select`, but the principle is the same).

Comment: Mmm, i get it know, you solved my problem, but, just to fully achieve my main goal, I was planning on pass a property instead of a plain value as you suggested to get a better performance, but can't get the fully depiction of the end result, we were talking about, instead of `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>`, something like `Func<TEntityListing, Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>>` or `Expression<Func<TEntityListing, TEntity, bool>>` or maybe (I don't know how to create it but) `Expression<Func<TEntityListing, Func<TEntity, bool>>>`. So I can be focused in the final Type and try to do it.

Comment: No, you don't need to change the type of the generated expression, nor the usage. Just the implementation, see the answer (many times it's easier to show some code than explain :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the explanations it was pretty clear that there is some issue with `ParameterExpression`s of the dynamically built predicates. And at the end it was in the one of the custom expression extension methods used.

While technically it could be considered ORM bug/issue, they have to solve very complex things during the expression tree transformation, so we must be tolerant and fix our code when possible.

There are some important things you need to be aware of when building dynamically query expression trees.

First, the name of the used `ParameterExpression`s doesn't matter - they are identified by *reference*. It's perfectly fine to have all parameters with one and the same name (something that C# compiler won't allow you to create at compile time) as soon as they are separate instances properly referenced by the other expressions.

Second, some things which make sense when creating expression trees for compiling and executing as code (like in LINQ to Objects) are not good for expression trees which are supposed to be transformed to something else (they are valid, but make the transformation harder and lead to bugs/issues). Specifically (what was causing the issue in question) is "calling" lambda expressions. Yes, there is a dedicated `Expression.Invoke`, but it is causing issues with almost all `IQueryable` implementations, so it is better to emulate it by "inlining" it, which means replacing parameter instances inside the body with actual expressions.

Here is the modified version of your `ExpressionExtensions` class applying the aforementioned principle:

```cs
public static partial class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
        => Combine(left, right, ExpressionType.AndAlso);

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(this Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right)
        => Combine(left, right, ExpressionType.OrElse);

    private static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Combine<T>(Expression<Func<T, bool>> left, Expression<Func<T, bool>> right, ExpressionType type)
    {
        if (left is null) return right;
        if (right is null) return left;
        bool constValue = type == ExpressionType.AndAlso ? false : true;
        if ((left.Body as ConstantExpression)?.Value is bool leftValue)
            return leftValue == constValue ? left : right;
        if ((right.Body as ConstantExpression)?.Value is bool rightValue)
            return rightValue == constValue ? right : left;
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(Expression.MakeBinary(type,
            left.Body, right.Invoke(left.Parameters[0])),
            left.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression Invoke<T, TResult>(this Expression<Func<T, TResult>> source, Expression arg)
        => source.Body.ReplaceParameter(source.Parameters[0], arg);
}
```

which uses the following little helpers for parameter replacing:

```cs
public static partial class ExpressionExtensions
{
    public static Expression ReplaceParameter(this Expression source, ParameterExpression parameter, Expression value)
        => new ParameterReplacer { Parameter = parameter, Value = value }.Visit(source);

    class ParameterReplacer : ExpressionVisitor
    {
        public ParameterExpression Parameter;
        public Expression Value;
        protected override Expression VisitParameter(ParameterExpression node)
            => node == Parameter ? Value : node;
    }
}
```

As confirmed in the comments, this solves the issue in question.

---

Now, unrelated, but as a bonus. Another thing which makes sense for expressions supposed to be compiled is the usage of `ConstantExpression`s - they are evaluated once and then used in potentially many places.

However for expression trees which are supposed to be transformed to SQL or similar, using `ConstantExpression`s makes each query different, thus non cacheable. For performance reasons, it is better to use expression type which is treated as *variable*, thus allowing the cache the transformation and parameterizing the generated SQL query, so both client and database query processors can reuse the "compiled" query/execution plan.

Doing so is quite easy. It does not require changing the type of the predicate or the way you generate. All you need is to replace the `ConstantExpression` with *member* (property/field) of a `ConstantExpression`. In your case it's a matter of replacing

```cs
var propertyValue = pi.GetValue(entityFilter);
```

with

```cs
var propertyValue = Expression.Property(Expression.Constant(entityFilter), pi);
```

and of course adjusting the signatures/implementation (in general try to not use specific expression types if they are not essential for the method), e.g.

*FilterByPropertyAttribute* class:

```cs
public abstract Expression GetExpression(ParameterExpression parameter, Expression value);
```

*NonNullableValuePropertyFilterAttribute* class:

```cs
public override Expression GetExpression(ParameterExpression parameter, Expression value)
{
    var property = this.GetPropertyExpression(parameter);
    if (value.Type != property.Type)
        value = Expression.Convert(value, property.Type);
    return this.GetExpression(property, value);
}

protected abstract Expression GetExpression(MemberExpression member, Expression value);
```

*EqualPropertyFilterAttribute* class:

```cs
protected override Expression GetExpression(MemberExpression member, Expression value)
    => Expression.Equal(member, value);
```

All other things, including the usage remain the same. But the result would be nicely parameterized query as if it was created at compile time.

Comment: Astonishing Ivan, this really helped me out, and for what i saw you even taked your time to simplify the `And` and `Or` definitions by delegating the wanted `Type` to the `MakeBinary` method.
And for the bonus part I was really out of track in my mind, it really was more easy than what I expected.
Anyways, thanks for helping me!

Comment: Absolute gold! Thanks Ivan for this!